# Div height is overflowing issue

Tags: html, css

I'm have a one div element on my web page that contains both image and text-content, which are both separate classes. both of the elements are fixed side by side within a given margin. I am trying to control the text-content element from overflowing other elements in the page. My aim is to reduce its height according to the height of the image so that the two elements are dependent on each other. how would I do this?

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 1):

Put the image and text into their own `<span>` tags. Set the height of the parent div to the height you desire and then set the overflow options on the span with the text in appropriately.

If you know javascript you can set the parent div to adjust to the height of the image and ensure the overflow options on the text are set correctly.

There are probably a bunch of other ways of doing this but this is the one that came to mind for me.

Comment: Thanks! Looked for a solution for some time before stumbling on your answer. Did the trick!